# Python 3 Why returns None

Tags: python

Why is None returned ?
When a or b is 0, max(a, b) must be returned

```
def gcd(a, b):
if a == 0 or b == 0:
    return max(a, b)
else:
    if a > b:
        gcd(a-b, b)
    else:
        gcd(b-a, a)
```

print(gcd(1000,400))

Comment: Your indentation is broken, make sure this is not the case in the code you actually run.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You aren't returning when you recursively call `gcd`.

```py
def gcd(a, b):
    if a == 0 or b == 0:
        return max(a, b)
    else:
        if a > b:
            return gcd(a - b, b)
        else:
            return gcd(b - a, a)
```